# Processing NLTK Stanford POS Tagger output

Tags: python, nltk, stanford-nlp

Im working with NLTK Stanford Pos Tagger with my own model to tag line of sentences in text file. The output of my tagger is like :

```
sentences = [((Word,WordTag),....(Word,WordTag)]
```

Im processing Indonesian language, Im doing 2 step after doing Pos tag :

1. Stop Word Removal
2. Stemming

I've got a list of stopword in text file(`stopword.txt`), and Stem the sentence. 
So far I have done the tagging part. I dont have any ideas how to filter the word in `sentences`  and remove the word if they in `stopword.txt` and stem the word in `sentences`

So far, i've tried this code to remove the word but still not removing the word and its word tag:

```
stopWords = getStopWordList('id_stopword.txt')
filtered_sentences = [w for w in sentences if not w in stopWords]
    filtered_sentences = []
    for w in sentences:
        if w not in stopWords:
            filtered_sentences.append(w)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to assume that your function `getStopWordList()` correctly returns a list of strings. (Have you verified that?)

The code you posted won't run because it has indentation errors. But the indented bit doesn't matter because you don't need it. It clearly just repeats the logic of the line before it. So I've just ignored it.

To do the filtering you need to change this:

```
filtered_sentences = [w for w in sentences if not w in stopWords]
```

to this:

```
filtered_sentences = [(w,t) for (w,t) in sentences if not w in stopWords]
```

Comment: yes , the getStopWordList() return a list of strings. Thank you.  Now the remaining problem is the stemming. Can i use the following code to stem the filtered_sentences?

Comment: Post a separate question about stemming. Your code didn't make it into your comment. Probably too long.